# How to sum through two tables in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for help to sum values in a table using a mapping table..
Tried Xlookup and sumif. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Simplifying it in an example

Basically, I have two tables.

| Food type | Food |
| --- | --- |
| Fruits | Apple |
| Fruits | Orange |
| Vegetable | Spinach |
| Vegetable | Fenugreek |

| Food | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | $10 |
| Orange | $15 |
| Spinach | $20 |
| Fenugreek | $10 |

So, if my input is Foodtype = Fruits, then I should get an answer of $25 (as it will sum up Apple and Orange)..

The combination of sumifs and xlookup is only giving one answer ($10) whereas I need $25.
please let me know.
I cannot combine the tables, as I have to use the first mapping table in multiple places.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(E2:E5,FILTER(B2:B5,A2:A5=I2),F2:F5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou.. let me try it out.

Comment: Thankyou, this worked.. I will learn more about the filter function. Guess that did the trick!

Comment: Quick question - Why is a sum required after the sumif? Wouldn't the sumif do it after it has identified that Apple, Orange are filtered

Comment: @user898727 because ```SUMIF``` returns range.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `XLOOKUP` and `SUM`.

```
=SUM(XLOOKUP(FILTER($B$2:$B$11,$A$2:$A$11=G2),$D$2:$D$5,$E$2:$E$5))
```

[image]